# Kite: not running

Tags: jupyter-lab, kite

for me, with jupyterlab 3.0.16 and jupyterlab-kite 2.0.2 and kite engine running, the bottom still says "Kite: not running" after I restarted the kernel many times.Why?

Comment: Restarting kernel will not fix Kite. Refreshing JupyterLab might work though.

Comment: @krassowski can't work

Answer (score 1):

Kite doesn't seem to be working with jupyterlab 3.0.16 at the moment. I had the same problem for a week and then I installed version 3.0.14 and seems to be working now.
Try installing jupyterlab 3.0.14

`pip install jupyterlab==3.0.14`

The problem is also mentioned [here](https://github.com/kiteco/issue-tracker/issues/532#issuecomment-848496594).

Answer (score 1):

Their download page says it is temporarily unavailable, switch to tabnine instead